# Introducing automatic currency conversion into web templates

Tags: php, currency

On my site I give prices in US dollar and pound sterling. I did myself the conversion using online tools then I wrote the results into my web template.

Is there an easy way to have this calculation done on the fly for me, so that even when currency rates change, the values on my site are up to date without me having to update anything?

So for example I want to announce $50 for product A and $100 for product B, and after each price in dollar I would have a price in pound sterling between parenthesis that is actually calculated programmatically for me.

Comment: You can do this by finding a source for exchange rates. The problem is that everyone has slightly different rates they offer. What you actually get at your bank when someone from another country buys might be different. A common strategy is for you to pick a conservative exchange rate and update a file on your site periodically. This can backfire, though, in times of rapid shifting of exchange rates. Either you lose money or you are charging so much that your customers go elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just quick hints:

1. create a DB table(s) for storing actual currency rates
2. create a script that will be executed by `cron` e.g. each hour (or once a day, depending on the online tools service and conditions of use)
3. on each execution the script will download the currency rates and store them to Your DB table(s)
4. then the conversion could happen online using the rates queried from Your own DB table(s)

using this approach You have actual data almost all the time (currency rates should change only once a day) and You are not connecting to a third party API every time while the conversions are *real-time*...

IMHO, instead of connecting to external services every day (thus the rates are changing every day) I'd stick with *my own currency rates* that I set once per month and are advanteguous enough.